# Is it possible to call kernel function from user code?

Tags: c, linux-kernel

I'm very new to Linux and C programming and the question may seem quite dumb.

I'm trying to learn how to develope a simple LKM and read the following article: https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/04/linux-lkm-basics/

But this is not exactly what I was looking for. The think was that I wanted is that to load the LKM and allow user to call some function my LKM provides which us going to be executed inside the Kernel space and use some Kernel specific functions

Is something like this ever possible? Or I should look towards another direction?

Comment: Not directly — there's a hard wall between the kernel and user code, and the system calls (and signal handling) carefully control transitions between the two.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler So I need to design some sort of my own `syscall` if I want to be able the user code is able to communicate with my hand written LKM. Is that possible to do?

Comment: Yes, it's possible to design your own system call — or perhaps device driver — and then use that to call your kernel-mode functions (LKM — Loadable Kernel Module).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I searched for this and as far as I could understand it is only possible to overwrite an existing system call so designing a fake device looks much portable choice. The question is if there are some concurrent concernes that can arise when readinf/writing to the device from multiple processes?

Comment: Yes, there are lots and lots of issues with writing kernel mode code.  You need to read a lot before you do it.  I wouldn't try without spending a day or two reading about the rules, finding some examples, experimenting with them.  Yes, concurrency control will be an issue.

Comment: There is no easy/portable way to add sys calls, so it's best to make do with what is already available. A common way is to structure your LKM as a device driver. Have the LKM create a virtual device. Then have the user mode code open your device, and then issue an `ioctl` command to the device. An `ioctl` can do arbitrary things with arbitrary arguments and can both receive data from user space and provide data back to user-space. Your process can also do a `write` to the device to command the device to do something, and/or `read` from the device to get data back if that is more convenient.